# Windows 10 - Export and Import Local-Group-Policy (Windows-Update) Changes

Tags: windows, command-line, group-policy

Concerning-System: `Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC | Version  10.0.17763 Build 17763`

i have changed the local group policy via editor:
[image]

through research following command should export the the whole group-policy (with my personal changes):

```
%windir%\System32\secedit.exe /export /db defltbase.sdb /mergedpolicy /cfg %userprofile%\documents\Sec.inf /log %userprofile%\documents\secedit_error.log /quiet
```

**Error**
defltbase.sdb not found

**INFO - Relating to my personal experiences**
Parameter: `/db defltbase.sdb without adding a path is accessing C:\Windows\System32` but on this Windows10-Machine the file does not exist.

Other Sources talk about the file `C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb`
this file exists
the export-file-output is empty after the secedit command
conclusion: my personal changes aren't stored in this file

Other sources talk about copying `%systemroot%\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol`, but they talk on the other hand about many problems like MACHINE-NAME and stuff that will also copied on the next machine. But in my oppinion this is the most unprofessional solution for this case.

**OBJECTIVE**
how can i export the changes with cmd and migrate them to another machine?
Where are the changes in the group-policy-editor stored, where is this specific *.sdb-file?